# Jsoup with GWT (Make a compatible JAR)

Tags: parsing, gwt, jsoup

I want to use Jsoup as an external JAR with GWT on the client-side.
But the .jar of Jsoup is not made for GWT. (no .gwt.xml).

I'd need to package the Java files along with the class files and a .gwt.xml file to be able to use it as a module and inherit it in GWT.

But I don't know how to do.

Link:
Jsoup - http://jsoup.org/

Thanks

EDIT: My application has only a client-side. No server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any java decompiler to extract java classes and add them to your src folder. Or you can download sources and attach them to project. Should work.

**UPD**

1. To avoid such errors you have to move classes to client package.
2. Even then those classes won't work. Because this library uses java classes that not present in GWT mapping (java->js). So the best suggestion is to try to rewrite conflicting imports yourself.

**UPD2**

As I can see there only 4 conflicts. It should be easy.

Comment: I tried but I've got errors during the compilation:
_com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
....
[unresolved] public void title(java.lang.String) 
[unresolved] public Unresolved type org.jsoup.nodes.Element createElement(java.lang.String) 
[unresolved] public org.jsoup.nodes.Document normalise()_



And a lot of other [unresolved].

I only copy the classes ? Nothing to add in the .gwt.xml for example ?

Comment: Not only 4 conflicts. I couldn't write them all. (not enough space in this comment box).
I moved the classes to client package.
I don't understand the second part (rewriting import). I've got something like this in my class:

`package com.domain.appgwt.client.jsoup.nodes;

import com.domain.appgwt.jsoup.helper.Validate;`

The errors look like this now :

[ERROR] Line 64:  The method format(String, String) is undefined for the type String

[ERROR] Line 181:  The method clone() is undefined for the type Object

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I mean that in GWT not all standard java methods are present. For example java.net.URL is missing, String.format is not implemented. You should find each case (just google it - lots of examples) and write 'gwt-compatible' code instead of conflicted lines.

Comment: Ok. Well it seems that it will take a lot of time, i'm gonna search for an other parser... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you can't do that.
A possible approach is to use JSoup on the server-side and make RPC calls from the client to retrieve the desired data.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a server-side actually. The data I want to parse is from a String